Jmeter execution error shows java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
I am trying to test my database with Jmeter. I would just like to see whether I can establish a connection.
I installed the necessary dependencies via Maven, for postgres and jmeter
Total error code is:
22:13:11.597 [main] ERROR org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine - Unable to execute testStarted(null) for test element org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement@a9aedfb2
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:671) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:777) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.initPool(DataSourceElement.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.testStarted(DataSourceElement.java:128) ~[ApacheJMeter_jdbc-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:247) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:432) [ApacheJMeter_core-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:197) [classes/:?]

This is the code I try to execute:
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Database Reachability Test Plan");

        ListedHashTree testPlanTree = new ListedHashTree();
        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);

        DataSourceElement dataSource = new DataSourceElement();

        dataSource.setProperty("dataSource", "MyPostgreSQLDataSource");
        dataSource.setName("MyPostgreSQLDataSource"); // Hier wird der Namen festgelegt
        dataSource.setProperty("dbUrl", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres");


        dataSource.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setProperty("username", "postgres");
        dataSource.setProperty("password", "postgres");
        dataSource.setAutocommit(true);
        dataSource.setPoolMax("0");
        dataSource.setProperty("connectionAge", "5000");
        dataSource.setProperty("timeout", "10000");
        dataSource.setProperty("trimInterval", "60000");



// JDBC Sampler
        JDBCSampler jdbcSampler = new JDBCSampler();
        jdbcSampler.setName("Database Reachability Test");
        jdbcSampler.setProperty("dataSource", "MyPostgreSQLDataSource");
        jdbcSampler.setQuery("select * from street;");



It's pretty clear that JMeter is expecting a String that can be parsed into a number, but it's getting an empty string instead. The real question right now is where this is happening. Then when you locate where, the "why" will become more clear. I would start by setting some breakpoints and running the code through the debugger to locate the issue -- probably something you should have done before posting.

Just look at DataSourceElement.java:221 and see what property it wants.

Change this line:
dataSource.setPoolMax("0");

to this one:
dataSource.setProperty("poolMax", "0");

Also be aware that if you want to use JMeter GUI for checking/debugging/sharing your test plan it makes sense to set TestElement.TEST_CLASS and TestElement.GUI_CLASS properties as well.
Check out JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test article for more information and jmeter-from-code repo for example code snippets
